# Webpack 4 Configuration for angular 4 - Will Compile with errors but cannot find files on page load

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

Ok so its well known there is very limited documentation for the migration to webpack 4..

So I followed there guide here https://webpack.js.org/concepts/ looked at the angular guide for webpack and well here is what I have so far.

My angular app is as it is on the angular webpack tutorial

**Directory Structure** [image]

**My Dependencies...**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~4.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~4.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "~4.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~4.2.0",
  "@angular/http": "~4.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "~4.2.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "5.0.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
  "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
  "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "ts-loader": "^4.3.1",
  "typescript": "^2.9.1",
  "webpack": "^4.10.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.0.1",
  "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
}
```

**My tsconfig**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
   mode: 'development',
   devtool: 'inline-source-map',
});
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry:{
        polyfills: './src/main.ts',
        vendor: './src/main.ts',
        main: './src/main.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    }
}
```

Ok so im using npm scripts but I also have webpack globally installed both on version 4 when I run `webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js` I have two issues

1 - I am getting the following warning.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 5644:15-36 10:13-37
 @ ./src/main.ts
```

Secondly whe I actually go to view the app its saying that the main/js and vendor and polyfills cannot be found. What am I doing wrong. Ive foolowed all the examples looked over the typescripts worked through about 10 tutorials but none seem to cater for webpack 4. I have removed JsUglify and other issues like that just to make a minimal boiler plate.

What am I doing wrong

**PLEASE NOTE THE ANGULAR WEBPACK SAMPLE AS PROVIDED BY ANGULAR DOES NOT WORK !!" hense the ened for building a boilerplate for scratch, secondly all the other examples run webpack 2/3 or angular 2/6 not very helpfull

Comment: Have you found this [upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/)?

Comment: Yes, the issue is not with angular its either with my tsconfig or web pack setup. Angular-cli runs using webpack as default now. Build an app with that works perfectly, transfer the files and setup to my boilerplate, and nothing

Comment: I cannot believe that Ive had a down mark !!! You want to know the reason my question is unclear or unhelpful.... Because the docs for both Angular 6 & Wepack 4 are unhelpful.Will be posting working answer shortly to show the scale of how off the examples are

Answer (score 0):

In my webpack config i have defined the entrypoints by
`const entryPoints = ["inline", "polyfills", "styles", "vendor", "main"];`

using the HtmlWebpackPlugin

```
plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    "template": "./src/index.html",
    "filename": "./index.html",
    "hash": false,
    "inject": true,
    "compile": true,
    "favicon": false,
    "minify": false,
    "cache": true,
    "showErrors": false,
    "chunks": "all",
    "excludeChunks": [],
    "xhtml": true,
    "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
      let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
      let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
      if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
        return 1;
      }
      else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
        return -1;
      }
      else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
```